# How can I use Vite env variables in svelte.config.js?

Tags: vite, sveltekit

For example, in `.env.local`, I have

```
VITE_BASE=/sveltekit-ghpages
```

I can access this variable inside `src` using `import.meta.env.VITE_BASE`. But inside `svelte.config.js`, it doesn't work.

How can I use Vite env variables in `svelte.config.js`?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

If you are already using `dotenv` if your project then you can do this in your `svelte.config.js` file

```
import 'dotenv/config';

console.log("config", process.env.FOO)
```

Option 2:

If your node script is overloaded with environment variables, for example

```
...

"scripts": {
        "build": "FOO=BAR vite build"
}

...
```

then you can use `console.log( process.env.FOO)` without having to install dotenv `svelte.config.js` file

Comment: OP asks about variables defined in `.env` files provided by vite, not the OS environment. I  am sure dotenv will not know to load `.env.production` or `.env.test` vs. `.env` based on vite's build mode.